# How to make this Regex work?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-editing, notepad

i want to know how to make this Regex work `^....*:....* +[|].*$`

And `^....*:....* +[=].*$` And `^....*:....* +[-].*$`

It works without using **^** for first-line and **$** for end of line

Basically, i want to do Regex that targets from the first of each line to the end of line but **^** And **$** not working Do they have an alternative or a way to make it work?

**Source Test**

```
gfdgfdh4
fdgdgh4r:fe456ge | fsff | fefdgg
g5ghh5f:f4e84tger  | dsfg | wertyu5f6
aDFe84r!~#:fe45fgRte starbe593! = | = dsfg | wertyu5f6
fEett@$%6:fefesf4&*( - sfdfGghh - ewwefggh -ee f;fje
gfdgfdh4df564h54h
d4hdf8h4h
 fef   8efegg   98eef
r48y4hs6s:f5f4gvn4 | dd4f5g | qdsdb1r86 | qw98qer9 | gdfg4d7g478r
gdsg  45gdsgsd45 gdsgdsg45
```

**Output or Detecting With Regex**

```
fdgdgh4r:fe456ge | fsff | fefdgg
g5ghh5f:f4e84tger  | dsfg | wertyu5f6
aDFe84r!~#:fe45fgRte starbe593! = | = dsfg | wertyu5f6
fEett@$%6:fefesf4&*( - sfdfGghh - ewwefggh -ee f;fje
r48y4hs6s:f5f4gvn4 | dd4f5g | qdsdb1r86 | qw98qer9 | gdfg4d7g478r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.{4,}:.{4,}[-\|].+$`
- Enable Wrap around
- Search Mode: Regular expression

Comment: Thank you Reddy Lutonadio
it works <3